# file attachment in webmail of plesk

Tags: plesk, webmail

I use plesk control panel for my windows server .i give this error when attach a file with webmail.

This feature (add attachment) is only available to licensed installations of MailEnable. The license key is either missing or invalid.

have any idea for this problem .

Comment: Have you using MailEnable from plesk installation or you modify it somehow? What is version and edition of MailEnable?

Comment: I use mailenable webmail version 8

Comment: What is the size and type of attachment? I've tried to reproduce this, but can't see any license limitations or warnings, or errors.

Comment: when i click on the attachment button i give this error for any size or any file type.

Comment: Check for my answer again, there is several workarounds in MailEnalbe forum http://forum.mailenable.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=26241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[update]**

Looks like bug in MailEnable 8 installation http://forum.mailenable.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=26241

---

For a quick solution you can switch domain's webmail to Horda Webmail Client, but in this case all of specified settings of this webmail client like Calendar, Address book, Notes etc will not transfered to new webmail.